# remove/unset a zk node data without deleting its children

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I am trying to unset a zookeeper node's data through its CLI. The target node has multiple children underneath and I do not want them to be affected by this. So, was wondering if there is any command for this. rm and rmr are not helpful in this case as they remove the entire path.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to set an empty string as a value:

```
set /path/to/node ''
```

It doesn't unset the data, just overwrites it with an empty string.